# auto-renew certbot with Cloudflare

Tags: cloudflare, lets-encrypt, certbot, auto-renewing

I am running `nginx` and `cloudflare`. For `nginx` `ssl` I use `letsencrypt` via `certbot`, which handles the connection from my server to `cloudflare`. `cloudflare` itself has an additional `certificate`, which handles the connections between `cloudflare` and the website users. The problem is now that I have to `pause` `cloudlfare` everytime when I renew `letsencrypt`:

```
sudo certbot renew
```

Else I get an error:

> Incorrect validation certificate for tls-sni-01 challenge requested.
>   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
>   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
>   contain(s) the right IP address.

Is there another way to `auto renew` it without pausing cloudflare?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this before and thought some Cloudflare page rules would help

**Rule 1** http://*.domain.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/*  => cache level = standard

**Rule 2** http://*.domain.com/ => Always use HTTPS

This seemed to work fine for all my domains until just today, one of them failed to renew certbot correctly, so I am also interested in anybody else's input.

Answer (score 1):

Log into CloudFlare and go to DNS

You will see an A/AAAA record and if it says Proxied, you need to set it to DNS Only. Then you can go and do `certbot renew` and it will succeed.

If you go back to Cloudflare you can set it back to Proxied

Comment: Yes! that always work but is there a way that auto renew works automatically?